# Prove A is open if and only if w+A is open, A is closed if and only if w+A is closed.

Tags: real-analysis

Let A be a subset of $\Bbb R^n$ and let $\mathbf w$ be a point in $\Bbb R^n$. The translate of A by $\mathbf w$ is denoted $\mathbf w$ + A and is defined by $$\mathbf w+A \equiv \{\mathbf w + \mathbf u\mid \mathbf u\text{ in A}\}.$$ $\mathbf a.$ Show that A is open if and only if $\mathbf w$ + A is open. 
$\mathbf b.$ Show that A is closed if and only if $\mathbf w$ + A is closed. 
 For part $\mathbf a.$ I know that if A is open then $\mathbf u$ is an interior point of A. Is it correct to say: $$ \therefore  \mathbf w + \mathbf u \text{ must be an interior point of } \mathbf w + A \implies \mathbf w + A \text{ is open.}$$  and I'm not sure how to get started on $\mathbf b.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For part (a), it suffices to show that $B_r(w+a) = w + B_r(a)$. But this is easy since
$$x\in B_r(w+a) \iff ||x-(w+a)||<r$$
$$\iff||(x-w)-a||<r$$
$$\iff x-w\in B_r(a)$$
$$\iff x\in w+B_r(a)$$

For part (b), just note that any set $S$ is closed iff $S^c$ is open. So, 
$$A\text{ closed } \iff A^c \text{ open }$$
$$\iff w+A^c \text{ open }$$
$$\iff (w+A)^c \text{ open }$$
$$\iff w+A\text{ closed } $$

Comment: Hi @MPW, that is just for one inclusion, what about showing that $w + B_{r}(a) \subseteq B_{r}(w+a)$?

Comment: @Overachiever : It is not for just one inclusion. It is for both. Note these are double-headed arrows, so the implication chain is reversible.

Comment: @MPW If A is open and B is closed, is A+B both closed and open because of part (a) and (b)?

Comment: @Mikalo : No. The only sets that are both closed and open are $\varnothing$ and $\mathbb R^n$. The argument fails because $A+B= \bigcup\limits_{a\in A}(a + B)$. The union is the problem.

Comment: @MPW Why is the union the problem? Since the union of closed sets is closed right?

Comment: @Mikalo : No, only the union of *finitely many* closed sets is guaranteed to be closed. After all, every set $S$ is a union of closed sets since $S=\bigcup\limits_{s\in S}\{s\}$ and each $\{s\}$ is closed.

Answer (score 3):

The function $\phi(x) = x+w$ is a homeomorphism (continuous with a continuous inverse) hence it maps open sets to open sets and closed sets to closed sets (since closed sets are the complements of open sets).

Note that $w+A = \phi(A)$.